# How to snap jQuery draggable on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

### [Please see the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wLk9/55/)

Currently draggable is getting snapped to the droppable from distance of 15px. Rather than snapping based on fixed pixels specified in snapTolerance, is there any way I can snap it to the target when the cursor(draggable) is over it? I have tried to spend lot of time on it. But could not find a workaround.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about exactly what you want, but it looks like you are on the right track with the `tolerance: 'pointer'` and `snapTolerance: 15` options.

Can you get what you need by just tweaking the tolerance, for example: `snapTolerance: 37`? That way, as soon as the cursor is on top of the target, the draggable snaps right into place.